# How to cancel multiple setState calls using abort controller or cancelable promises

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I have this `init` function that is called in `componentDidMount` or other functions that are called when interacting with the user:

```
protected async init() {
    if (this.props.requiredSource)
    ) {
      this.setState({ imageSource: this.props.requiredSource });  // task I want to cancel in componentWillUnmount;
      return;
    }

    // ... more code here ....

    const exists = await RNFS.exists(uri);
    if (exists) {
      this.cropImageForDisplayView(uri); // async that needs canceling in componentWillUnmount
      this.iAmUploading(); // async that needs canceling
      return;
    }

     this.setState({ imageSource: { uri: httpUri } }); // same here
     return;
    }
    try {
      // ...more code here...
      this.setState({ imageSource: { uri: `${httpUri.split('?')[0]}?w=${size.w}&h=${size.h}&min=1` } });  // same here
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ imageSource: { uri: httpUri } }); // same here
    }
  }

  private iAmUploading = async () => {
    if (this.props.tempFileId != null) {
      this.setState({ tempfileId: this.props.tempFileId }); // same here
    }
  };
```

The above code needs some refactoring because it generates some classical `update component that doesn't exist` errors.

I would need an answer about best practices how to use abort controller or cancelable promises to cancel the multiple setStates calls and the async tasks when the component doesn't exist anymore.

I've looked into:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

but that article is 5 years old it is not very clear to me if that is the best practice in these days and how I could adapt that to cancelling multiple async tasks and setState calls.

Any help that does not include the classic anti-pattern `this.isMounted` will be greatly appreciated.

Note: current app is written with classic components (without hooks) and a refactoring towards hooks is not possible at this moment.

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Standard approach described in multiple react tutorials (including [the one](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data#abort-data-fetching-in-effect-hook) linked in the official react docs) is to set a flag when component is unmounted, and check this flag after each async step of your code. This is probably ok for a single async call - but becomes quite verbose if you have multiple async calls that are chained one after another.
2. A bit cleaner solution for those more complex cases could be achieved with a library that provides cancellation out of the box. Abovementioned `cancelable-promises` or `bluebird` provide promise-compatible implementations that allow cancellation.
3. A different approach would be switching to using Observable-based api with `rxjs` instead of
   promise-based. Observables are cancelable by design. A drawback though is that you won't be able to use `async`/`await` with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [cancelable-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cancelable-promise) to make your promises cancelable. Like this:

```
import { cancelable } from 'cancelable-promise';

protected async init() {
    // ... code here ....

    const exists = await RNFS.exists(uri);
    if (exists) {
      this.cancelableCropImageForDisplayView = cancelable(this.cropImageForDisplayView(uri));
      this.cancelableIAmUploading = cancelable(this.iAmUploading());
      return;
    }

    // ... code here ....
  }
```

Then in componentWillUnmount you just need to cancel your promises.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   this.cancelableCropImageForDisplayView.cancel();
   this.cancelableIAmUploading.cancel();
}
```

Bear in mind that your promises will still be executed but the result will be discarded. If you want to really cancel the execution as soon as componentWillUnmount runs you need to make sure that your async calls support some kind of interrupt signal (something similar to [Axios cancellation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)).

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend the following approach yet, because the [CPromise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2) library is currently in beta stage, so it's just for awareness.

When you use `CPromise` instead of native to build promise chains, all asynchronous tasks, including nested ones, become completely cancelable/abortable- when the cancel method is called, they will be rejected with the special `CanceledError` reason. The internal async jobs built on callbacks will be terminated as well if the user code supports the `cancel` event processing. If you use ECMA asynchronous functions, you need to subscribe the promise chain to the external AbortController signal.

[Decorators usage demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-classes-decorators-tiny-forked-34vf2?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { async, listen, cancel, timeout } from "c-promise2";
import cpFetch from "cp-fetch";

export class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: ""
  };

  @timeout(5000)
  @listen
  @async
  *componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted");
    const response = yield cpFetch(this.props.url);
    // more tasks
    this.setState({ text: `json: ${yield response.text()}` });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.text}</div>;
  }

  @cancel()
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("unmounted");
  }
}
```

Here an example how to write cancelable code ([live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-ardinghelli-7r6o8?file=/src/App.js)):

Answer (score 0):

If you're using axios, you need to generate a cancel token for each request to make it cancellable.

Ref: https://codesandbox.io/s/cancel-requests-with-axios-reactjs-forked-6v9rf